# Uploading Web with Fancy Box to server [ PROBLEM WITH FANCYBOX IFRAME]

Tags: html, fancybox

Hi to all and thanks in advance for your support.

I've been working in an HTML file with a Fancybox iframe integration. In my computer it´s working and the fancy box feature work well but when I uppload the files to the server the Fancy Box iframe feature doesn't works.

Please find attached the files and the code of this issue.

1º Screenshot of the Fancy Box Iframe working in local server:

[image]

2º When I  upload the website to the server (HOSTALIA), the fancy box doen´t work (it´s a link to the website, not an iframe inside the website). Find bellow a Screenshot of the Fancy Box Iframe not working in Hostalia server:

[image]

And finally Please find attached the code that I am using in the html file.

'''

WEB FANCY BOX

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fancybox.min.css">


<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>


<style>

    h2{
        clear:both;
    }

    .single-image img{
        width:256px;
        height:auto;
    }
    
    .gallery-image img{
        width:256px;
        height:auto;
        float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
    }
    
    .fancyOther2{
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    

</style>

<script>

    $(function(){
    
        $(".single-image").fancybox({
            openEffect : 'elastic',   //'fade', 'elastic'
            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed:'normal', //ms, slow, normal, fast (default 250ms)
            closeSpeed:'normal',
            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside' //'float', 'inside', 'outside' or 'over'
                },
                overlay : {
                    closeClick : true  // if true, se cierra al hacer click fuera de la imagen
                }
            },
            padding:11
            
        });
        
        $(".gallery-image").fancybox({
            openEffect : 'fade', 
            closeEffect : 'fade',
            closeBtn: false,
            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'over' //'float', 'inside', 'outside' or 'over'
                },
                thumbs : {
                    width: 50
                },
                buttons : {},
                overlay : {
                    css : {
                        'background' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
                    }
                }
                
            }
                            
        });
        
        
        $(".fancyOther").fancybox({
            width       : '70%',
            height      : '70%',
            maxWidth    : 800,
            maxHeight   : 600,
            fitToView   : false,
            autoSize    : false,
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none'
        });
        
        
        $(".fancyOther2").click(function(){
            $.fancybox( '<div><h1>Lorem Lipsum</h1><p>Lorem lipsum</p></div>', {
                 title : 'Custom Title',
                 width      : '70%',
                height      : '70%',
                maxWidth    : 800,
                maxHeight   : 600,
                fitToView   : false,
                autoSize    : false,
                closeClick  : false  
            });
        });
        
        
        $(".fancyMedia").fancybox({ 
            helpers : {
                media : {}
            }
        });
        
        $(".fancyMediaMapa").fancybox({ 
            helpers : {
                media : {}
            },
             width      : '100%',
            height      : '100%'
            
        });

        
        
    
        
    });
    
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="row align-items-center" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
                    <div class="col-md-6"><a class="fancyOther" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="https://1clickdesign.virtualmarketcenter.com/pub/render/model-viewer/festatic/3dviewer?obsbgid=3FO4KL101VN9&kpm=qkWL.6553558902bac74b.ff3a030.1573116354633&locale=en_US"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="assets/img/3D%20viewer%20540x308.jpg"></a>
                    </div>
    </div> 
    
</body>
```

'''

Thanks in advance for your feedback and support

Comment: You probably forgot to upload any file... Check devtools if there is any 404. your HTML is correct if it works locally.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the http that must be https.

Thanks to all the people that have read it.